# Why is accessing a null-terminated string giving 'garbage or undefined'?

Tags: c, clang, clang-static-analyzer

I have a simple brainfuck interpreter in C that produces the following warning in `scan-build`:

```
$ scan-build gcc -Wall -g -std=c99 main.c 
scan-build: Using '/usr/bin/clang' for static analysis
main.c:14:11: warning: Assigned value is garbage or undefined
        c = *(program + instruction_index);
          ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
scan-build: 1 bug found.
```

Here's the smallest version of my program that exhibits this behaviour:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <alloca.h>

void eval_program(char *program) {
    int program_len = strlen(program);
    int data_index = 0, instruction_index = 0;

    char c;
    while (instruction_index < program_len) {
        c = *(program + instruction_index);

        switch (c) {
        case '>':
            data_index++;
            instruction_index++;
            break;
        default:
            instruction_index++;
            break;
        }
    }
}

char *read_string(int file_descriptor) {
    char *s = NULL;
    int total_bytes_read = 0;

    int BUFFER_SIZE = sizeof(char) * 1024;
    char *temp_buffer = alloca(BUFFER_SIZE);

    int bytes_read;
    // Not bothering checking the return code from read or realloc for
    // errors, because it doesn't affect scan-build's output.
    while ((bytes_read = read(file_descriptor, temp_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE))) {
        s = realloc(s, total_bytes_read + bytes_read);
        memcpy(s + total_bytes_read, temp_buffer, bytes_read);
        total_bytes_read += bytes_read;
    }

    s = realloc(s, total_bytes_read + 1);
    s[total_bytes_read] = '\0';

    return s;
}

int main() {
    char *program = read_string(0); // read from stdin
    eval_program(program);
    free(program);

    return 0;
}
```

This program does not generate any warnings when compiled with GCC and `-Wall -Wextra`, so why is accessing the string garbage or undefined? The program works fine in my testing.

This is a minimal example without error checking `malloc` or `read`, but [the warning still occurs if I use error checking](https://gist.github.com/Wilfred/edbbdd8b61d3aef1d52a). The warning also occurs if I replace `realloc` with `malloc`.

Comment: I don't really see any problem in the program, have you read about what the warning means in `clang`'s documentation?

Comment: @nos yep, the same error. Note that `temp_buffer` is never passed to `realloc`.

Comment: @user3121023 true, but as the comment says, fixing that doesn't silence this error. I tried to keep my example short, but [see this version for the same warning even when checking for errors](https://gist.github.com/Wilfred/edbbdd8b61d3aef1d52a).

Comment: The incriminated code looks OK to me, so it looks like a false positive. Are you using the latest version of `scan-build`?

Comment: I'm running clang-analyzer 3.5.1.

Comment: As an aside, why do you use a side-buffer in `read_string` anyway?

Comment: @Deduplicator what do you suggest instead?

Comment: Reading directly into the target buffer? Also, `sizeof(char)` is a bit superfluous.

Comment: Does the error report change if you check the return value from `malloc()` or `realloc()` for nullness?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reduce the read_string() function to this:

```
char *read_string(int file_descriptor) {
    char *s = NULL;

    s = malloc(1);
    //memset(s,0,1);
    s[0] = 0;

    return s;
}
```

If you comment in the memset() call, the warning goes away. I therefore conclude that the static analyzer is wrong in this case.

Comment: Well, at least that gives a concise bug-report then.

Comment: Thanks, I've filed [bug 22289](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22289) based on your minimised version.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the code.

This is a false positive bug in LLVM's clang-analyzer, see [bug 22289](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22289).